# Looking for an equivalent to manual triggers in "Delivery Pipeline Plugin"

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to implement a post-build manual trigger like in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin using Pipeline?
Using "input" unfortunately is not appropriate in this case.

Something like

```
stage "Testing stuff" 
  node("slave") { 
    git credentialsId: "blahblahblah", url: "git@github.com:blah/blah.git" 
    sh """testing something"""
  }

stage "Building stuff" 
  node("slave") { 
    git credentialsId: "blahblahblah", url: "git@github.com:blah/blah.git" 
    sh """building stuff""" 
  }

input message: "Deploy?" 
stage "Deploying stuff" 
  node("slave") { 
    sh """Deploy stuss"" 
  }
```

Comment: Please include some code showing how you have tried to solve this problem. You should also tag your question with the appropriate language.

Comment: This is more a plugin question then language question per say.

Comment: I was hoping something like the following would work, but "input" keeps the build running unlike manual triggers in "Delivery Pipeline Plugin". 
`stage "Testing stuff"
node("slave") {
    git credentialsId: "blahblahblah", url: "git@github.com:blah/blah.git"
    sh """testing something"""
}

stage "Building stuff"
node("slave") {
    git credentialsId: "blahblahblah", url: "git@github.com:blah/blah.git"
    sh """building stuff"""
}

input message: "Deploy?"
stage "Deploying stuff"
node("slave") {
    sh """Deploy stuss""
}`

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information. And presumably this is a "plugin" for something bigger? It's just that both your tags are very low volume and including as many **applicable** tags as you can, will ensure your question is seen by more viewers. (I have no idea what Jenkins is, BTW.)